# Get acces to parent while clicking ContextMenu WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, contextmenu

I have set of nodes and I create image to represent each of them on WPF Form.

```
        BitmapImage src = new BitmapImage();
        src.BeginInit();
        src.UriSource = new Uri("pack://application:,,,/WpfApplication1;component/Resources/Node.png", UriKind.Absolute);
        src.CacheOption = BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad;
        src.EndInit();

        foreach (var item in nodeList)
        {
            Image newImage = new Image();
            newImage.Margin = new Thickness(item.Position.X , item.Position.Y , 0, 0);
            newImage.Source = src;
            Canvas1.Children.Add(newImage);
            newImage.MouseRightButtonDown += newImage_MouseRightButtonDown;
        }
```

My delegate creates ContextMenu for every image placed on form.

```
    void newImage_MouseRightButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        ContextMenu menu = new ContextMenu();

        int index = Canvas1.Children.IndexOf((Image)sender);

        MenuItem addExistingLink = new MenuItem();
        addExistingLink.Header = "Add Existing Link";
        addExistingLink.Click += submenu_Click;

        MenuItem addNewLink = new MenuItem();
        addNewLink.Header = "Add New Link";
        addNewLink.Click += submenu_Click;

        menu.Items.Add(addExistingLink);
        menu.Items.Add(addNewLink);
        menu.IsOpen = true;
    }
```

And then delegate for my submenu Click event

```
    void submenu_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

    }
```

How can I get acces to my Image when clicking on this Context Menu?

Sender returns MenuItem type

```
        var item1 = sender;
```

This returns MainWindow type

```
        var item2 = this;
```

Parent returns ContextMenu type

```
        var item3 = item1.Parent;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try setting the `DataContext` of your `ContextMenu` to an object that has access to the `Image`:

```
ContextMenu menu = new ContextMenu();
menu.DataContext = this;
```

Or:

```
ContextMenu menu = new ContextMenu();
menu.DataContext = this.DataContext;
```

I'm just guessing here, but you should be able to work which object has access to the `Image` control.

Comment: `menu.DataContext = ((Image)sender);` instead of `menu.DataContext = this;`

Comment: Thanks for updating... so, did that fix your problem?

Comment: I had to add one more line `var item1 = ((MenuItem)sender).DataContext;`
           `Image item2 = ((Image)item1);`

Comment: Please add this code to the end of your question, so that your solution will be easily found by future users. Many thanks.